# Kreiss matrix theorem for general induced norms

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, operator-theory, normed-spaces, spectral-norm

As part of the theory of non-normal operators, the Kreiss matrix theorem states that if $A$ is a $N \times N$ matrix, and $\|\cdot\|$ is the spectral norm, then
$$\mathcal{K}(A) \leq \sup_{k \geq 0} \|A^k\| \leq e N \mathcal{K}(A),$$
where $e$ is the Euler number and $\mathcal{K}(A)$ is the Kreiss constant of the matrix, defined by
$$\mathcal{K}(A) = \sup_{z \in \mathbb{C} , |z|>1}(|z|-1)\|(zI - A)^{-1}\|$$

Does this theorem only hold for the spectral norm, or does it extend to any induced norm, i.e. $\|\cdot\|_p, p \in [1, \infty)$, at the price of perhaps changing the definition of $\mathcal{K}(A)$ to be in terms of this $\|\cdot\|_p$ norm? I could not find any reference for a more general claim. Any pointer would be much appreciated.

Note: It is immediately possible to derive naive upper and lower bounds using Hölder-type inequalities for matrices, but this breaks the dependency in $N$ of the Kreiss matrix theorem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that "this breaks the dependency in $N$ of the Kreiss matrix theorem"? It looks like the theorem already has some dependency on $N$

Comment: Well, I could say for example for an upper bound that $\|A\|_1 \leq \sqrt{N} \|A\|_2$ and then use the theorem but I am picking up an extra $\sqrt{N}$ along the way.

Comment: Okay, but what concretely is bad about the extra $\sqrt{N}$? It is incorrect to say that you have "broken dependency" in some way, but perhaps you mean that you're specifically looking for an optimal bound, or perhaps a bound of the same order $O(N)$

Comment: By breaking the dependency I meant that it was in $O(N)$, and now it is worse. Thanks for helping me clarify!

Comment: Ok, that makes things much clearer, thank you. Do you know of any texts or papers that give a proof of the Kreiss matrix theorem? I would suspect that the ideas could be adapted to arbitrary norms

Comment: Proofs usually go through complex analysis. Here is a reference for a sub-optimal constant http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/~trefethen/publication/PDF/1984_22.pdf.

Comment: I suspected there must have been some complex analysis involved since there's a resolvent.  It seems like it should be possible to tweak this result for arbitrary $p$-norms

Comment: In particular, I think that one could make use of the fact that 
$$
\|A\|_p = \max\{|u^*Av| : \|u\|_q = \|v\|_p = 1\},
$$
where $1/p + 1/q = 1$.

Comment: Following through, it does preliminarily seem that it would suffice to change $\mathcal K(A)$ to be in terms of the $p$-norm. However, this bears careful verification that I don't currently have the patience for.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. This characterization of the $p$ norm is very promising, I wasn't aware of it, where do you get it from? I'll do the verification.

Comment: I don't have a reference off the top of my head, but the idea is pretty simple. By Hölder, we have
$$
|u^* (Av)| \leq \|u\|_q \|Av\|_p \leq \|A\|_p \cdot \|u\|_q \cdot \|v\|_p.
$$
From there, you just need that the Hölder's inequality becomes an inequality for a suitable choice of $u$ (for $p \notin \{1,\infty\}$, this occurs when $u$ is a multiple of $Av$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111910/discussion-between-ippiki-ookami-and-ben-grossmann).